# Have xcode step into every line of code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, step-into

I'm trying to understand how a functionality works and then rewrite this  functionality by stepping through the code while it is running to see exactly what it is doing. However, I'm noticing that Xcode is not stepping through every line of code. There is an instance, and I noticed it in a block, where the debugger just skips when I continuously press the step into button. It will stop if I put a breakpoint in one of the lines in the block, proving that Xcode is not going through this line by line, and it means it must be running lots of code that is not shown to me.

How can I make Xcode step through every line of code?

Comment: Don't optimize the code.  At all.

Comment: "Stepping into" a block doesn't make sense.  Blocks are typically passed as a parameter to another function and may or may not be called later.

Comment: @HotLicks, most useless comment, ever. You have no idea of the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a breakpoint inside a block if it's being used in a `dispatch_async` or similar call. This is because that block of code is copied somewhere (usually a queue), and then executed separately. Often on a different thread.

Comment: The problem is I don't know where all the code that is being run is. That's one of the reasons I'm stepping through it line by line because I want to know where all the code are.

Comment: Can you see what queue the code is being added too? You'll likely see something like: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...` or `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),...`. That first parameter is telling what queue is being used. Those two examples are built in queues, but it's possible the code creates it's own queue as well. The queue itself will execute code blocks added to it.

Comment: It's nothing to do with threading; the debugger just doesn't follow the indirect call. `void inv(dispatch_block_t block){ block(); }; inv(^{ /* do something */}; );` would be the same.

Comment: Yes, all the async stuff are not stepped through unless I have a breakpoint in them. Any way to make xcode step through async stuff?